# Access local file system from Web App

Tags: javascript, java, file, applet, npapi

Let's say End Users have a value or token stored in their PC (let's say a file) and I want to get that value from browser (JavaScript) and it will be done automatically (No manual upload).

The only browser End Users are allowed to use is Google Chrome, and it doesn't support NPAPI so I suppose I can't use Java Applets. I was thinking about a Chrome extension, plugin or maybe a standalone application that interacts with browser to "pass" the value.

**The only thing that matters is getting that value from End Users PC automatically**

Any ideas are welcome and appreciated.

EDIT 1: I The value is generated by a desktop program, so I can't use localStorage (I guess)

Comment: Is that value is created by the same origin of website? If so, you can use HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: the browser can't access the files system. if you want to persist data then you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910833/accessing-a-local-directory-from-a-chrome-app

Comment: maybe you can try to create a desktop app using [electron](https://electron.atom.io/). you can think of electron as a web app wrapper with chrome and filesystem access. the user has to install the app you create however.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the value is generated by a desktop program so I can't use localStorage.

Comment: *".. it doesn't support NPAPI so I suppose I can't use Java Applets"* Correct.